# React-fiber (drei) ScrollControls prevent<Html> from scrolling

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-three-drei, react-fiber, drei

I've noticed in V9 of drei there is a bug when combing the `<Html>` elment with `<ScrollControls>`.

I just want bind text to a 3D element but the ScrollControll makes the text scroll out of the view: [CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollcontrol-drei-working-1treb3)

It works fine in v8: [CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollcontrol-drei-working-forked-gl995r)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this in this PR https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/pull/1126 we just have to wait until they approve it. But you can just patch the library yourself using https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package, it should be easy as it is just one line change.

Edit: Now that I think about it, you could probably fix it also by sending `gl.domElement.parentNode` as the portal prop.